# Jump to another activity when clicking a item in menu of actionbar in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-actionbar

This is the code for select items in menu, when user click logout, the activity jumps to login_activity, when user clicks account, the activity jumps to account_activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.logout_id:
            Intent login = new Intent(MainpanelActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(login);
        case R.id.account_id:
            Intent account =new Intent(MainpanelActivity.this,AccountActivity.class);
            startActivity(account);
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

However, during the testing, no matter what i click, the activity always jumps to the account activity.

If i switch the order of the switch cases

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.account_id:
            Intent account =new Intent(MainpanelActivity.this,AccountActivity.class);
            startActivity(account);
        case R.id.logout_id:
            Intent login = new Intent(MainpanelActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(login);

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

no matter what i click, the activity always jumps to the login_activity. Anybody knows why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `break;` to in each case like below. Otherwise your code will execute the case that satisfies the switch condition and each case after it until either a `break;` or the end of the `switch` is reached.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.account_id:
            Intent account =new Intent(MainpanelActivity.this,AccountActivity.class);
            startActivity(account);
            break;
        case R.id.logout_id:
            Intent login = new Intent(MainpanelActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(login);
            break;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```